# Run-time check failure #3

Tags: visual-studio, runtime

i get a run-time check failure #3 for the variable pParam. I thought initialization is here:

```
{BYTE*  pKey;
BYTE*   pParam;
DWORD   KeyLen = 0;
DWORD   ParamLen = 0;
```

The run-time error occures in this line:

```
*ppParam = pParam;
```

I'm using Visual Studio whith Visual C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *pParam is in an if clause, the variable will never been initialized. You should check this. You should initialize the variable with *pParam=NULL;.